# Find & Replace with regular expression using Batch (Windows)

Tags: regex, windows, findstr

I should replace the following:

```
   something="A1" with something=""
   something="BB" with something=""
   ...
   something="NN" with something=""
```

like in notepad++ would be `something="[^"]+" something=""`

Comment: Please clarify the set of characters to search for. You mentioned A1, BB, and NN but does this include lowercase characters? What about numbers > 1? How about number 0? Any special characters to include? Are letters beyond 'N' allowed?

Comment: ahhh sorry. It should contains all chars (low/up), numbers and specials chars too. thnx M